# How to save redux state per user transaction

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a redux react web app booking court app and I want to manage/store redux state based on the user unique id that is coming from the server when the user initials the booking. Currently my initial state looks like this:

```
 const initialState = {
        payload: [],
        loading: false,
}
```

I have a reducer like

```
const courtReducer = (state =initialState, action: any) => {
      switch(action.type) {
      case MAKE_BOOKING:
        return {
         ...state,
         loading,
         payload: action.data
        };
       other action...
      }
}
```

I am not sure if I am making sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to figure out how to *store* state, maybe the ["Sending Data with Thunks" section](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#sending-data-with-thunks) of the Redux documentation will help. It's part of a tutorial which should leave you with a pretty good idea of how to integrate async API calls with reducers.